# Android viewflipper bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

When I am using viewflipper using a button click it transits from right to left. But the view moves a little inside and again bounces back. Imagine something like a spring effect. I suppose this is some bug.
This is the xml code:

```
        left.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
        android:startColor="#212121"
        android:centerColor="#404040"
        android:endColor="#212121"
        android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
         Viewflipper in main layout
         <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/viewflipper" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:inAnimation="@anim/left"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/right"
        >
```

Comment: I doubt there's a bug in ViewFlipper. Please post more code.

Comment: @OcuS Is this enough for now?